# How do you all debug edge cases happen on customized ROM (Like CM7)

Tags: android

Recently, we had released an app. Before we releasing, we tested it on Samsung Nexus S, Samsung Galaxy S and Samsung Galaxy Tab.

However, recently, we realize our app cannot detect the front camera, for users who are running **HTC EVO 4G Cyanogen 7**

I was wondering, how do you guys start to debug on such edge cases, without purchasing new hardware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The joys and sorrows of platform fragmentation, especially where custom firmware is concerned. The short answer? You can't test all the edge cases, and you'll certainly never catch the CM-derived defects. It's the nature of the beast. Even independent branches of the CM baseline do their own things that may entirely break something (e.g. the front camera) or get something else working (.e.g the CPU sleep). I mean, think about it: custom firmware is *by definition* custom. I could have -- and do! -- my own branch of CM7 that I could do anything in the world with. I could make it so that it ignores the ldpi resources altogether and always pulls hdpi, regardless of dot pitch or anything else. And, more importantly, I could completely screw it up. Unless you run my branch, you won't see that behavior.

The best you can do is program for the largest platforms (targeting API level 7 currently nets you about 99% of the overall market) and then wait for the edge cases to be reported and handle them as quickly as possible. Acquire devices that can cover the vast majority of platforms based on your spending resources. Elect beta testers to receive early builds on esoteric devices or firmware.

Then keep your fingers crossed :).

Comment: And, for cases where the stock firmware works on a device but a modded ROM does not, report the bug to the mod maintainers. For example, if the EVO 4G's original ROM works fine (based on testing through DeviceAnywhere-style services, or based on analytics showing you lots of EVO 4G users and no other crashes), then the problem may well lie with CyanogenMod 7.

Comment: That's the joy and sorrows. However, most of the time, clients just do not understand and will put the blame on us :)

Comment: Quite true. I also realized you asked how to _debug_ edge cases on those hardware platforms, not just catch them early. That's a different can of worms. Unless you can find a willing owner, you'll have to acquire the device if it's custom firmware based, or at least have a comparable one in inventory that you can flash easily. It depends on the nature of the problem. A crash can usually be found regardless given code inspection and the stack trace. Things like not finding the camera are a bit trickier without the actual hardware :|.